# TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[9], "../../config/FIREBASE").FIREBASE.database')

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, syntax-error

I have installed Firebase with npm in Firebase, but I don't know what happens with this error.

#### File *FIREBASE.js*

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAd2EBoYYCRWEc3oClZTV3Wo-TiQkM2MgQ",
    authDomain: "crud-react-26836.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://crud-react-26836-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app",
    projectId: "crud-react-26836",
    storageBucket: "crud-react-26836.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "741718079918",
    appId: "1:741718079918:web:1566301b46c4448c8c703f"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const FIREBASE = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default FIREBASE;
```

*TambahKontak.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity, Text, Alert } from 'react-native'
import { InputData } from '../../component'
import { FIREBASE } from '../../config/FIREBASE'

onSubmit = () => {
    if (this.state.nama && this.state.nomorHP && this.state.alamat) {
        console.log("Masuk Submit");
        console.log(this.state);
        const kontakReferensi = FIREBASE.database().ref('kontak');
```

Comment: Is the file name actually *"FIREBASE.js"?* Not *"firebase.js"*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using the new Modular/Functional syntax which is included from version `9.0.0+`. You would have to rewrite your code to follow the new syntax:

```js
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database"

const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
const snapshot = await get(child(dbRef, 'kontak'))
```

If you want to use the existing code (with older syntax) then use `compat` version by changing the imports to:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/database'
import 'firebase/compat/[SERVICE_NAME]'

const FIREBASE = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default FIREBASE;
```

I'd recommend using the new version and following the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) for learning more about it.

Comment: Ok thankyou and now how to import to TambahKontak.js so that FIREBASE.database() can use at TambahKontak.js. But now i am using firebase v.9.0.0 , first statement at FIREBASE.js can't be use again.

Comment: You can just export database from `firebase.js` directly. `export const database = firebase.database()`

Comment: ok thank you, i want to be your student for react native. I am Nicholas from Indonesia

Comment: firebase.js
// Initialize Firebase
const FIREBASE = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = FIREBASE.database()
export default database

main.js
import { database } from '../../config/FIREBASE'
const kontakReferensi = database.ref('kontak')

TypeError: FIREBASE.database is not a function. (In 'FIREBASE.database()', 'FIREBASE.database' is undefined)

Still error like this sir

Comment: export this `export { database }` and then import this: `import { database } from "..path/to/firebase.js"`. Then you don't have to call `.database()` again. Just create a Database ref like this `database.ref("/path/to/data")`. I'd recommend following the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) for detailed examples.